# Current_page doesn't work on updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial for displaying transaction in financial app.

```
<%= form_for @transaction ... do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= transaction_name(@transaction) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In this partial I need to display `transaction.name` differently, depending from current page.

My `transaction_name` helper is:

```
def transaction_name(t)

  # Create name
  if t.name.present?
    name = t.name
  else
    name = 'Some default text'
  end

  # Update name if transaction has debt
  if t.debt.present? and !current_page?(debts_path) # <- problem is here
    name = t.debt.debtor.name + ' (' + name + ')'
  end

  name.html_safe
end
```

So, if user is NOT in `debts_path`, I want to add `Debtor` name to `Transaction` name. And everything works ok in `index` paths, but when I update transaction (it simply replace old transaction form with updated one), it always shows me `Debtor` name, even if I'm in `debts_path`.

Of course, transactions' updates goes through `transactions_controller` and `debts_path` is in `debts_controller`. Maybe the problem is here, but in fact I don't change `current_page`, while update transaction.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if t.debt.present? && "#{action_name}"!="index"
```